# Inserted managed objects properties are nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I use multi context Core Data scheme in my app. I have a class for network requests with method `- (void)getCurrencysWithParentContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)parentContext;`
Here i create an operation to parse xml-answer. This operation has own `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` context. In the end of the operation I call

```
if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        [self.parentContext performBlock:^{
            NSError *error;
            if (![weakSelf.parentContext save:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Parent context context save error %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Child context save error %@", error);
```

`self.managedObjectContext.insertedObjects` returns entities with not
nil attributes:

> (entity: Currency; id:
>   0x7a7b8cb0
>    ;
>   data: {
>       charCode = RUR;
>       nominal = 1;
>       orderNo = 0;
>       rates =     (
>       );
>       sbrfID = nil;
>       sign = "\U20bd";

But `weakSelf.parentContext.insertedObjects` returns

> (entity: Currency; id: 0x7a7b8cb0
>    ;
>   data: {
>       charCode = nil;
>       nominal = 0;
>       orderNo = 0;
>       rates =     (
>       );
>       sbrfID = nil;
>       sign = nil; for the same objectID.

Why? What do I do incorrect? How to properly push changes to the parent context?

Comment: I'm worried that because the save in the parent context is scheduled with a block, that you're checking it before the `save` happens...  ?

Answer (score 0):

From the Core Data Programming Guide:

> **Saving in a Background Thread is Error-prone**
>
> Asynchronous queues and threads do not prevent an application from quitting. (Specifically, all NSThread-based threads are “detached”—see the documentation for pthread for complete details—and a process runs only until all not-detached threads have exited.) If you perform a save operation in a background thread, therefore, it may be killed before it is able to complete. If you need to save on a background thread, you must write additional code such that the main thread prevents the application from quitting until all the save operation is complete.

Just save the child context and if successful save the parent context without bothering with the concurrency APIs.